# External Content Type - SQL - Filters

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, filter, external-content-type

I create a new external list via a new external content type SQL .

I retreive my data and i can display it.

BDC Service allows us to view 2000 items .

> 1st Issue:
>
> I can filtered through a filter to limit 2000. However I'd like to
>   display the 2000 last entry in the SQL database and I can not. It
>   takes me the first 2,000 entries .
>
> Is it possible to view the last 2000 entries in the SQL database ?

Edit: This problem came from my SQL base. SharePoint Designer Filter do what i want know.

**2nd Problem:**

He retrieves a System.Decimal type column , my values ​​are only integers, but It displays a value with ten decimal 0 ( 20.000000000000000000 ) .

**Is it possible to limit the number of 0 it displays ?**

Thank you in advance,
EGuidez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my BDC Model,

I added "cast([Quantity] as int) as" before [Quantity] :
[image]

And it display correctly Quantity as an int:
[image]

Problem Solved :D

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for 2nd Problem:**

I guess your database table column type as decimal(18, 20). If you correct it into decimal(18, 0) then you will not get decimal value in suffix.

**Solution in SharePoint**

By default external list have **Read List.aspx** view.

By editing view in SharePoint Designer you can control the decimal value.

Step 1: Open the list in SharePoint designer

Step 2: click the view/create new view and open the view page in Advanced Edit mode.

Step 3: Select the column you need to control and click **formula** ribbon button under **Filter, Sort & Group tab**.

Step 4: Add formula  `substring-before($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name],'.')`

After above update you will found following XSLT code
`<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name],'.')"/>` in code view.

**Screen shot Update:**

Open External List in designer and click on **Read List.aspx** view page see below

[image]

Next view the page in Design View or Split as shown below

[image]

Now select your column by click the TD of your column as shown in image then click the formula as shown in picture.

Comment: I selected : <FieldRef Name="Quantity"/> in my <view/>
But i can't see Filter,Sort & Group Tab ...
I'm in advanced edit mode

Comment: You Correct in Advanced edit mode you not allowed to access Filter, Sort & Group Tab. Select the field in design mode and then try it out

Comment: I took a [screen](http://i.imgur.com/BWPCtyP.jpg).
I can't see Filter,Sort & Group tab. 
Maybe i don't understand ... I haven't activated "Advanced Edit mode" in my screenshot.

Comment: Ok fine now see the updated answer above.

Comment: Ok, we have a problem.
**Description of the change.SharePoint Designer 2010 has three views for editing HTML and ASPX pages: Code view, Design view, and Split view. Design view and Split view are removed from SharePoint Designer 2013.**

Comment: Oh are you using SPD 2013? I will check in SPD 2013 and let you know

Comment: Yes, i'am.
I'm working on sharepoint 2013 with sharepoint designer 2013.
Can i use Sharepoint 2010 ?
They are many features that MS delete on 2013 version of designer.

Comment: No SPD 2010 not allowed to open SP 2013 site. Any how your aim is possible in SPD 2013 also. I will come up with answer ASAP